# Android ADT Errors finding DDMS

Tags: android, adt, ddms

I downloaded the most recent ADT to start learning how to do some Android Development (I have tried it before but didn't go far with it). So after following the list of things Google says to do I'm now getting the following errors within my application project, I have no idea as to why though.

```
eclipse.buildId=v21.1.0-569685
java.version=1.7.0_09
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

Error
Mon Mar 25 15:38:30 GMT 2013
Failed to load properties file for project 'MyFirstApp'
```

&

```
eclipse.buildId=v21.1.0-569685
java.version=1.7.0_09
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

Error
Mon Mar 25 15:37:56 GMT 2013
DDMS files not found: D:\Users\Matt\Documents\Android\eclipse\platform-tools\adb.exe
D:\Users\Matt\Documents\Android\eclipse\tools\hprof-conv.exe 
D:\Users\Matt\Documents\Android\eclipse\tools\traceview.bat
```

As I'm fairly new to all this I have no idea what the issue is, I was expecting that just downloading the ADT and following the guide would be good enough for me to figure out how to start devving, but clearly can't even get past the first stage. I believe this error is the reason I can't get my app to load into the Android Emulator also.

Comment: Verify that path set for android sdk is correct. You can do by going to Window -> Preferences -> Android

Comment: @Nitish Yeah the path is set to D:\Users\Matt\Documents\Android\sdk which is where everything is, I already check that but its odd the eclipse is looking in its own directory instead of the SDK path